# for loop creates a dictionary with x entries but after the loop, length of dictionary is < x

Tags: python, python-3.x, genetic-algorithm

So, I am implementing a genetic algorithm for TSP in Python. To calculate the next generation, I implement this function:

```
def nextGen(currPop, distDict, numChrome, mutRate):

     genFit = {}

     for i in currPop:
         tmp = fitness(i, distDict)
         genFit[tuple(i)] = tmp
         print(tmp)

     genFitCum = dictCum(genFit)

     print(len(genFit), len(currPop))

     parentSelection = parents(genFitCum, numChrome)

     children = breedPopulation(parentSelection, numChrome)

     nextGeneration = mutatePop(children, mutRate)

     return nextGeneration
```

`distDict` is the dictionary with distances between various cities.
`numChrome` is the number of chromosomes.
`mutRate` is the rate of mutation.

Now, after the first generation, I get the error for out of bounds which should not exist, since, it is all in loops.

The problem is that length of currPop is constant(numChrome) but length of genFit decreases. This is after the loop runs for numChrome times.

I thought maybe my implementation is hoarding on disk space. I tried using `del` but in vain.

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. In any event, I suspect that your keys aren't unique. What is in `currentPop`?

Comment: If the length of your dictionary is < x it means you have duplicate Keys.  Instead of inserting a new Value for a new Key it is just overwriting the Value of an existing Key.

Comment: I seriously doubt this is a memory issue.

Comment: You guys are right. My keys aren't unique. Was about to remove the question. Any suggestions on how to keep them unique? PS: Sorry for not maintaining the code of the website. Will take care next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check to see if your Key already exists before assigning a Value to it.

```
# Not sure if str(tuple(i)) will work - regardless apply logic like this to make the Key unique
counter = 0
while((str(tuple(i)) + '_' + str(counter)) in genFit.keys()):
  counter += 1
genFit[str(tuple(i) + '_' + str(counter)] = tmp
```